# Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() ->System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I try `Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()` this error occures:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to check if `UrlReferrer` is null, as it's not always set (ie, when someone typed the URL directly into the address bar, or clicked on a bookmark)...

```
(Request.UrlReferrer == null) ? "" : Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
```