# If a page 'A' is opened, find out from which source page page 'A' has been called?

Tags: asp.net

I am currently in "pageA.aspx". Using `top.location.href` or `Response.Redirect()`, I've come to "pageB.aspx". How to find out that which page has called "pageB.aspx". Is it "pageA.apsx" or any other page.

I aware of using URL Query-String. But I need to use any other option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Request.UrlReferrer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx).

> Gets information about the URL of the client's previous request that
>   linked to the current URL.

Comment: Felipe: Thnx for this idea. Actually it works in general. But in my required case, I'm coming to 'pageB' from 'pageA' which was opened in a radwindow. in 'PageA', Using 'top.location,href = pageA.aspx', I navigated to 'PageB'. But here Request.UrlReferrer is showing NULL. WHY ??

Comment: Hi @Kings: It depends on how you redirect the user to some other page. In this case you are using this top.location.href

Comment: Can you change the way you are calling the web page?

Comment: In addition, whether you are calling the web page from other site, you can avoid this error in this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187866/request-urlreferrer-tostring-system-nullreferenceexception-object-reference

Comment: Felipe:- I surely would. But as explained before I'm opening 'pageB.aspx' in a radwindow, from the base page 'pageA.aspx'. So, on a button click event I have defined in JS to close the radwindow and reoload the base page, using  top.location.href. I don't know any other way : (

Comment: Felipe:- Getting null is not an issue. I just a refernce in 'pageB' that pageA' has called it. Getting NULL is of no use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732742/asp-net-response-redirect-not-populating-url-referrer